# using variables of one perl file in another

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am writing two perl script which requires  an array consisting long list of strings
Here I wanted to declare my array in a separate perl package and use this package to access that array in other two perl scripts

Can you please tell me how could i do this

I checked for perl cpan  module Exporter, but could find it can export subroutines,I only want my array to be exported not any subroutines

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Exporter` can handle any package symbol, be it a subroutine or variable:

```
package My::Package;
use parent 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT_OK = qw/@foo/;

our @foo = (42, 666);
```

Then:

```
use My::Package qw/@foo/;

print "@foo\n";
```

Output: `42 666`.

However, package variables (aka. “globals”) are frowned upon. Usually, techniques like object orientation provide a better solution. If you don't want to go there, you could still write a kind of “accessor” or “initializer”:

```
package My::Package;

sub main {
  my @foo = (42, 666);
  return \@foo;
}
```

Then:

```
use My::Package;

my $foo = My::Package::main();
print "@$foo\n";
```

Comment: :how can i add this module in directory (@INC)  so it can be used in any perl script

Comment: @ar777 (1) Place it in any directory, then `use lib '/your/module/root'` in any program that requires your modules. This is the easiest solution. (2) Set the environment variable `PERL5OPTS='-I/your/module/root'`. (3) Upload your module to CPAN, then install it from there. [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org/) can help (but has a steep learning curve).

Comment: Thank you for explaining multiple options

Answer (score 1):

You can create a package variable and export it, just like a subroutine:

```
package Local::Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);  # Allows you to export things

our @EXPORT = qw(@foo_array);

our @foo_array = ( ... );
1;
```

Now, you can use it in your program:

```
my @local_array = @foo_array;
```

This is called *a really. really bad idea*. Variables are polluting your main program's namespace without your knowledge. Plus, you could change `@foo_array` and destroy its special meaning.

If you go this route, do not do the export. Simply refer to the variable directly via the package name. After all, you've declared it with `our`:

```
package Local::Foo;

...

our @foo_array = ( ... );
```

And, in your program:

```
my @program_array = @Local::Foo::foo_array;
```

This is a tiny bit better. You won't have namespace collisions, and you know where that value is coming from. However,  I would take the lead of `use constant` which uses subroutines to define constants. When you say this:

```
use PI => 3.141529;
```

What you're really doing is this:

```
sub PI {
    return 3.141529;
}
```

That allows you to do this:

```
my $circumference = PI * ( 2 * $radius );
```

You could take a similar task with your array:

```
package Local::Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo_array);

sub foo_array {
    return qw( ... );
}
```

Now, to use this in your program:

```
use Local::Foo qw(foo_array);

...

my @program_array - foo_array;
```

You can access the value of `foo_array`, but you can't change it at all. It's totally protected -- a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have to echo amon's deprecation of exporting. You can create it as a *constant*

```
package TheData;
use constant BIG_ARRAY => [ 0..300_000 ];
```

And then other packages can reference it as if it were a static member:

```
package DataUser;

my $big_array_data = TheData->BIG_ARRAY;
```

Much cleaner for a more modern Perl. (Note that constant just is shorthand for what amon specified.)